# Flutter - what is needed to reload a network image when URL doesn't change

Tags: flutter

I'm just starting to learn app development with Flutter.

I am trying to build an app for learning purposes that grabs an image from a website using their API to get a random image. The app displays the image, and has a button which is supposed to grab a new random image when pressed.

The problem is that the URL for the API doesn't change, so Flutter thinks the image is the same and doesn't download a new image. At least, that's what I think is going on.

The code is very basic. So far just showing an image and a button. I've tried various things, and was thinking `imageCache.clear();` should do the job when the button is pushed, but nothing seems to work. I have also tried various tricks with resetting state and trying to navigate to the same page with named routes, but they all still show the same image (which is why I think it might be a caching issue). :shrug:

All of this is running from a single main.dart file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen[50],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Show Me The Lettuce",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
        ),
        body: ShowLettuce(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class ShowLettuce extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShowLettuceState createState() => _ShowLettuceState();
}

class _ShowLettuceState extends State<ShowLettuce> {
  String url = 'https://source.unsplash.com/900x900/?lettuce';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80.0),
                child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                    placeholder: kTransparentImage, image: url),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              imageCache.clear();
              print('button pressed.');
            },
            child: Text('Show Me A New Lettuce!'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've read through a lot of Flutter documentation, but I'm not yet at the point where I can interpret much of what they say into usable code (not sure where and how I'm supposed to plug it into my code, for example the imageCache documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageCache-class.html). It seems like this should be a really easy solution, but it is escaping me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved you problem.

You must add for your code couple lines code:

as first - import:

```
import 'dart:math';
```

next - in class _ShowLettuceState after declared url variable:

```
var random = new Random();
```

and for finish - after click the button, namely in onPressed:

```
setState(() {   
                url = 'https://source.unsplash.com/900x900/?lettuce' + random.nextInt(100).toString();
            });
```

Comment: While this does indeed allow a new image to be displayed, it's kind of a hack. I am hoping to use regular dart or flutter code to empty the image cache (or whatever needs to be done), rather than change the URL.

Comment: @AmmonShepherd I don't finded regular dart/flutter code that would work like you need.

Comment: This answer gets the job done, but not using regular dart/flutter code.

Comment: url + '?cacheBuster=' + DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this code :

```
String url = 'https://source.unsplash.com/900x900/?lettuce-${Random().nextInt(100)}';
```

This is inspired by @Captivity solution, but I add a `-` that makes it work.